# Routing problems one-to-one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations, one-to-one

I tried to route as following with my 2 models pimp and mepager (one-to-one relation):

**/config/routes.rb**

```
root :to => 'pimps#index'
get '/:pimp_id/mepager', :to => 'mepager#show', :as => 'mepager'
```

My mepager show action looks like this:

**/app/controllers/mepagers_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_pimp    

def show
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
end

private
def set_pimp
    @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
end
```

Now I tested in the rails console the function Pimp.first.mepager what should be equal to @pimp.mepager and it gives me the right mepager object back with all atttributes. But if I try to open '/:pimp_id/mepager' in my webapplication (with an existing pimp that has a mepager linked to it) I get following error

```
Routing Error
  uninitialized constant MepagerController
```

Did I miss something?

Regards.

Complete error msg:

> Started GET "/1/mepager" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-06 08:55:20 +0200
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant
>   MepagerController):   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
>
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in`
>   block in constantize'   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'   activesupport
>   (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in`inject'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in
>   `constantize'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in`controller_reference' 
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in
>   `controller'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each' 
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call' 
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in`
>   call'   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in
>   `call'   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in`
>   call'   activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in
>   `call'   activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in`
>   cal l'   activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in
>   `call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in
>   `_run__226962734__call__callbacks'   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks'   actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in`
>   call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`
>   call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>
>   railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'   railties
>   (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged'   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`tagged'   railties (4.0.0)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'   rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'   rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'   railties
>   (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call'   railties (4.0.0)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'   rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in
>   `block in start_thread'
>
> Rendered
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
>   /middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
>   /middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
>   /middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch
>   /middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout
>   (42.0ms)

Console test

```
> irb(main):001:0> Pimp.first.mepager   ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m 
> ←[1mUSE [rails_confreport_develop]←[0m   ←[1m←[35mPimp Load
> (1.0ms)←[0m  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [pimps].* Y
> [pimps].[id] ASC'   ←[1m←[36mMepager Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mEXEC
> sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [me gers] WHERE [mepagers].[pimp_id] =
> @0 ORDER BY [mepagers].[id] ASC', N'@0 int', id", 2]]
> => #<Mepager id: 2, pimp_id: 2, pre: "geqgewqrgq", post: "egewqewqgewqgewq", com .0, save_c: nil, save_other: "", save_otherv:
> nil, affect_design: "", affect_str "", affect_other: "", affect_dno:
> "", affect_mid: "", affect_otherdoc: "", owner ence: "", created_at:
> "2014-06-06 06:36:44", updated_at: "2014-06-06 06:36:44">
```

mepagers_controller.rb

```
class MepagersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mepager, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_pimp

  # GET /mepagers
  # GET /mepagers.json
  #def index
    #@mepagers = Mepager.all
  #end

  # GET /mepagers/1
  # GET /mepagers/1.json
  def show
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
  end

  # GET /mepagers/new
  def new
    @mepager = @pimp.build_mepager
  end

  # GET /mepagers/1/edit
  def edit
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
  end

  # POST /mepagers
  # POST /mepagers.json
  def create
    @mepager = @pimp.build_mepager(mepager_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mepager.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@pimp,@mepager], notice: 'Mepager was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @mepager }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @mepager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /mepagers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /mepagers/1.json
  def update
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mepager.update(mepager_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@pimp,@mepager], notice: 'Mepager was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @mepager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /mepagers/1
  # DELETE /mepagers/1.json
  def destroy
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
    @mepager.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to mepagers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_mepager
      @mepager = Mepager.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_pimp
      @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def mepager_params
      params.require(:mepager).permit(:pimp_id, :pre, :post, :comment, :save_h, :save_c, :save_other, :save_otherv, :affect_design, :affect_stress, :affect_me, :affect_other, :affect_dno, :affect_mid, :affect_otherdoc, :owner, :pps, :reference)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your `Controller classname`? It should be `MepagersController` as the file name is `mepagers_controller.rb`

Comment: Can you post the line at which it is showing the error?

Comment: I posted the whole error msg. As you can see its not giving me a specific line.

Comment: Can you post your `mepagers_controller.rb` with classname?

Comment: Done. Sry for bad format dunno whats the problem here.

Comment: @user3665315 try to remove your show action inside your :set_mepager filter. You don't need it there

Comment: Thanks you're totally right. But didnt solve the problem though :(

Comment: @user3665315 ok i think i got it. It'll be get '/:pimp_id/mepager', :to => 'mepagers#show', :as => 'mepager'

Comment: Yep, thats totally it! Forgot all my 's' on the controller actions in my routing! Thanks alot man. Id be happy to rate it if you post it as an answer!

Comment: @user3665315 i have added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written **get '/:pimp_id/mepager', :to => 'mepager#show', :as => 'mepager'** but it should be get **'/:pimp_id/mepager', :to => 'mepagers#show', :as => 'mepager'**. You forgot to add "s" in your "mepages#show". For more information refer to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

One more thing since your mepager is nested inside pimp you don't need your :set_mepager filter. You can either remove it or do something like this inside your mepagers_controller.rb

```
class MepagersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pimp
  before_action :set_mepager, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # your actions

  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_mepager
    @mepager = @pimp.mepager
   end

   def set_pimp
    @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your routes this way:

```
root :to => 'pimps#index'
get '/:pimp_id/mepager', :to => 'mepagers#show', :as => 'mepager'
```

Rails infers the controller name from the `:to` keyword. The notation `mepagers#show` means the `show` method of `MepagersController`

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code